# Swift iOS Formatting data from JSON codable / API with CustomStringConvertible

Tags: json, swift, formatter, customstringconvertible

I have some JSON that I would like to reformat before use, preferably in an initializer (or extension ??)

```
[
{
 "name": "Diesel",
 "id": "1",
 "maj": "2022-07-06 18:28:29",
 "value": "2.81"
  },
{
 "name": "SP95",
 "id": "5",
 "maj": "2022-07-06 18:28:29",
 "value": "2.048"
  }
]
```

I would like to ensure that the "value" data is always 3 decimal places. So in the above 2.810 instead of 2.81.

I have looked at CustomStringConvertible and in theory it looks possible, but I haven't managed to build a working version.

Mainly working from here https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/formatting-numbers-in-swift/

my Model looks like this :

```
struct Price: Codable {
    let name: String
    let id, maj: String?
    var value: String?
    var isCheapest: Bool?
        
}
```

I understand that I need to do some basic number formatting but I don't see how to integrate it with CustomStringConvertible or if this is the correct way to go about it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You want JSON or Price struct? Ie, encoding or decoding the JSON? I guess it's encoding. So you should use a custom `encode(to encoder: Encoder)` and in it ensure that the `value` output is 3 decimal. You can use a `NumberFormatter`  for that.

Comment: Do you want to make sure that the `value` should have 3 decimal alway when you access it?

Comment: Yes, always 3 decimal places when accessed. (decoding from JSON)

Comment: Consider that the value of `value` is a string, not a number. You can just append as many `”0”` as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use extension

```
extension Metric: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3

        let number = NSNumber(value: value)
        let formattedValue = formatter.string(from: number)!
        return "\(name): \(formattedValue)"
    }
}
```

Comment: As is, this give me an error on line 7 , No exact matches in call to initializer , I can build by changing it to:  let number = NSNumber(value: Double(valeur ?? "0.000") ?? 0.000) .. but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it like below

Extension to the string

```
extension String {
    var doubleValue: Double? {
        get{
            Double(self)
        }
    }

    var formatedValue: String? {
        get{
            // YOU HAVE TO MAKE SURE THAT THE STRING IS CONVERTABLE TO `DOUBLE`
            String(format: "%.3f", self.doubleValue ?? 0.000)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let price = Price(name: "Diesel", id: "1", maj: "2022-07-06 18:28:29", value: "2.81", isCheapest: false)
if let value = price.value?.formatedValue{
    print(value)
}
//Console Output - 2.810
```

Comment: This would work too thanks, but I think the extension on the model using CustomStringConvertible by Jayesh is a nicer solution. Numbers come back formatted in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the `String` value with a custom type, i.e `Wrapped` in the example below and implement `Codable` for it, which should work transparently for the underlying string value.

Also note rounding mode on number formatter, if you want to simply clip the fraction, then `.floor` should do it.

```
import Foundation

private let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.decimalSeparator = "."
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
    formatter.roundingMode = .floor
    return formatter
}()

struct Value: Codable {
    var wrapped: Wrapped
}

struct Wrapped: Codable {
    let source: NSNumber

    var doubleValue: Double {
        return source.doubleValue
    }

    init(_ doubleValue: Double) {
        source = NSNumber(value: doubleValue)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let stringValue = try container.decode(String.self)

        guard let numberObject = formatter.number(from: stringValue) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(
                DecodingError.Context(
                    codingPath: container.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Cannot parse NSNumber from String")
            )
        }

        source = numberObject
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        guard let stringValue = formatter.string(from: source) else {
            throw EncodingError.invalidValue(
                source,
                EncodingError.Context(
                    codingPath: container.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Cannot convert NSNumber to String"
                )
            )
        }

        try container.encode(stringValue)
    }

}

let value = Value(wrapped: Wrapped(11.234567899))
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(value)
let stringData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

// Prints: {"wrapped": "11.234"}
print("\(stringData)")


// Prints 11.234
let reverse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: data)
print("\(reverse.wrapped.source)")
```